# Dynamically created HTML5 canvas element in Kinetic.js fails with draggable:true

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I've been playing around with KineticJS and I've run into an interesting problem. I'm not really sure how to solve it.  Here is my code.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
// Kinetic Example
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 400
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 70,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable: true
});
// add the shape to the layer
layer.add(circle);
// add the layer to the stage
stage.add(layer);

// My doCircle function
function doCircle(ddata) {
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: ddata[1],
        y: ddata[2],
        radius: ddata[3],
        fill: '' + ddata[4] + '',
        stroke: '' + ddata[5] + '',
        strokeWidth: ddata[6],
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(circle);
    stage.add(layer);
}
// Data example (will be from user input)
var data = "circle 50 50 20 green blue 5";
// Make data an array
var arrData = data.split(" ");
// Get draw type
switch (arrData[0]) {
    case "circle":
        doCircle(arrData);
        break;
}
```

I've also made a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJcyY/)  for this.  You'll notice the the large red circle statically made is draggable.  The smaller green circle that I built using "data" when clicked, either disappears or sets to 0,0 on the canvas.  I'm assuming this is possibly a data type issue with data[1](http://jsfiddle.net/TJcyY/) and data[2] from the array on the x,y of the circle?  But if that were the case why does the element render correctly in the first place and only break when attempted to drag it?

Thanks for your help and solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Convert your incoming string data to numeric data with parseInt() and then you're good...**

```
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: parseInt(ddata[1]),
    y: parseInt(ddata[2]),
    radius: parseInt(ddata[3]),
    fill: '' + ddata[4] + '',
    stroke: '' + ddata[5] + '',
    strokeWidth: parseInt(ddata[6]),
    draggable: true
});
```

Also, are you intending to create a new layer every time inside doCircle?

Comment: this worked perfectly thank you. As for creating a new layer each time, I haven't really thought about that. I suppose I could instantiate layer once and just add to that layer. I haven't actually thought of my use case for this just tooling around right now.